# How to seperately save Keras encoder and decoder

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

I have trained an auto-encoder decoder using Tensorflow Keras

```
x_train = np.reshape(x_train, (len(x_train), n_row,n_col, 1))
x_test = np.reshape(x_test, (len(x_test),  n_row,n_col, 1))


input_img = Input(shape=(n_row,n_col, 1))

x = Convolution2D(16, (10, 10), activation='relu', padding='same')(input_img)
x = MaxPooling2D((5, 5), padding='same')(x)
x = Convolution2D(8, (2, 2), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = MaxPooling2D((3, 3), padding='same')(x)
x = Convolution2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
encoded = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)

x = Convolution2D(8, (2, 2), activation='relu', padding='same')(encoded)
x = UpSampling2D((3, 3))(x)
x = Convolution2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = UpSampling2D((5, 5))(x)
x = Convolution2D(16, (10, 10), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
x = Cropping2D(cropping=((5, 0), (1, 0)), data_format=None)(x)

decoded = Convolution2D(1, (10, 10), activation='sigmoid', padding='same')(x)

autoencoder = Model(inputs=input_img, outputs=decoded)

autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
```

I can save the total autoencoder model by using

```
autoencoder.save('...')
```

How can I save and access to the encoder and to the decoder separately from ?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have saved the `autoencoder` you can extract the `encoder` and `decoder` from the saved autoencoder likewise:

```
autoencoder= K.models.load_model('your_saved_autoencoder')

encoder = Model(autoencoder.input, autoencoder.layers[-2].output)

decoder_input = Input(shape=(encoding_dim,))
decoder = Model(decoder_input, autoencoder.layers[-1](decoder_input))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, since I have a deep autoencoder, autoencoder.layers[-1] doesn't work here

Comment: I've looked around a bit for your specific problem, and I think the way to save the encoder and decoder independently would be to create them as seperate models and then save them as you saved the auto encoder. You can refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54931203/15604484) for more clarity :

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign a unique name for last layer of encoder and decoder then you can reconstruct the encoder and decoder from autoencoder like this:

```
    encoderLayer = autoEncoder.get_layer("encoder")
    assert(encoderLayer != None)
    
    decoderLayer = autoEncoder.get_layer("decoder")
    assert(decoderLayer != None)

    encoder = Keras.Model(
        autoEncoder.input, 
        encoderLayer.output
    )

    decoder = Keras.Model(
        encoderLayer.output, 
        decoderLayer.output
    )
```